# Варианты со знаками препинания в присоединительных конструкциях

Tags: пунктуация

Мы любили наш павильон - может быть, потому, что он напоминал нам милые маленькие семейные коттеджи на картинках в детских книжках.

Почему здесь тире, а не запятая?

Если *может быть, потому, что он напоминал нам милые маленькие семейные коттеджи на картинках в детских книжках* является присоединительной конструкцией, то после вводного *может быть* в начале обособленного оборота разве можно ставить запятую по правилу вводного в начале и конце обособленного оборота.

Согласно Розенталю: За оградой мелькнули гипсовые статуи, голубые павильоны, — по всей вероятности городской сад (тире перед присоединительной конструкцией). После *по всей вероятности* нет запятой. Можно ли было здесь обойтись без тире? Оно - интонационное?

На сайте http://gaz20.spb.ru/img/download/trip_to_the_south.pdf опубликовано произведение Катаева "Поездка на юг", там без запятой перед тире, но после вводного - запятая.

За оградой мелькнули гипсовые статуи, голубые павильоны — по всей вероятности, городской сад.

А как же Катаев расставил знаки препинания?

Как их ставить согласно правилам?

Answer (score 1):

1) **Мы любили наш павильон — может быть, потому, что он напоминал нам милые маленькие семейные коттеджи на картинках в детских книжках.**

Тире интонационное, заменяет запятую, обозначая паузу между главной и придаточной частью.

Розенталь допускает **такое интонационное членение.** [§ 38. Тире в сложноподчиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142)

6) **интонационное отделение главной части от следующей за ней придаточной**: Вы спросите — зачем я пошёл на это?; А вы уверены — нужно ли это?;

2) **За оградой мелькнули гипсовые статуи, голубые павильоны — по всей вероятности, городской сад.**

**Такая пунктуация кажется логичной.**

Конструкция присоединительная (обособлена с помощью тире, что связано с отсутствием присоединительного союза). В начале ее находится вводное слово, но оно не выступает в роли союза, поэтому отделяется запятой.  Сравнить с обобщающим словом (такое же оформление): **Среди птиц, насекомых, в сухой траве — словом, всюду, даже в воздухе, чувствовалось приближение осени** (Аре);